# Add space to every line outside PHP code block

Tags: php

I know exactly what I want to realize, but I dont really know how to go about it with PHP.

I have made up some code that should serve as the concept of how it should actually be.

I want to indent every new line with X amount of spaces for the code that's out of the brackets.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?

I am not trying to do anything visual on the design, but rather have my code properly indented.

```
<?php
// Other PHP Code

foreach(explode("\n", $content) as $line) {
?>
```

This code outside the php block should be in the $content variable above to alter it.

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>

<?php
    echo str_repeat(" ", 4), $line;
}

// Other PHP Code
?>
```

Comment: Try using `"&nbsp;"` instead of `" "` --- using multiple `&nbsp;`

Comment: Or use *style="white-space: nowrap"*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: But how does it detect if the code's outside the brackets or not?

Comment: Beware of the [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: Ah, good question. Scratch that then @AmalMurali

Comment: Just out of curiosity what will this be used for?

Comment: Please clarify something: are you trying to visually indent the result (css, rendering...) or are you trying to indent the generated HTML code (so it looks good while looking at the source in a browser)?

Comment: Then see my answer - no code required.

Answer (score 1):

What about using css margin? You can give the line a class like this:
html:

```
<div class="myClass">here is my special text</div>
```

css:

```
.myClass{
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: But how would he able to detect whether the code is inside PHP blocks or not?

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything about the design. I just want to have my code properly indented, so it doesn't look like trash.

Comment: php won't be shown on the front end, so you mean in your editor? ifso,  just select the php and press tab....

Comment: If you don't like php in html then use a templating engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo str_repeat(" ", 4), $line;`

by `echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 4), $line;`

Comment: This wouldn't work at all. See my comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Indenting the source code itself works fine. No need for any fancy PHP code.

```
<?php
// Other PHP Code

foreach(explode("\n", $content) as $line) {
?>
    <!--Indent here!-->
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Content -->
        <?php echo $line; //assuming this is what you wanted to print ?>
    </div>

<?php
}

// Other PHP Code
?>
```

Notice how the HTML part (div) is indented. PHP will keep this indentation when generating the resulting HTML code.

Comment: http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier - If you are lazy. Indenting manually at development stage will always be preferable